# Android Decryption Throwing java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: IV must be specified in CBC mode

Tags: java, android, encryption

Despite checking that both my IV and derived keys are equal for encryption and decryption, it still throws the same error. The byte array will encrypt no problem, but decryption always fails. My decryption and encryption code looks like:

```
private final static int BLOCK_SIZE = 256;
private final static int IV_SIZE = 16;
private final static int ITERATION_COUNT = 10;
private final static String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
private final static String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

public byte[] encryptByteArray(byte[] plaintext, String fileName) throws InvalidKeyException
{
    extractIVfromName(fileName);
    genKey();
    
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(BLOCK_SIZE, iv);

        Log.d("encryptByteArray", "Size: " + plaintext.length + " IV SPEC: " +
                Base64.encodeToString(parameterSpec.getIV(), Base64.DEFAULT) + "DerivedKey: " +
                Base64.encodeToString(derivedKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT));

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, derivedKey, parameterSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here we have decryption, where the error is occuring:

```
public byte[] decryptByteArray(byte[] ciphertext, String fileName) throws InvalidKeyException
{
    extractIVfromName(fileName);
    genKey();
    try {
        //IV fails for some reason
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(BLOCK_SIZE, iv);
        Log.d("decryptByteArray", "Size: " + ciphertext.length + " IV SPEC: " +
                Base64.encodeToString(parameterSpec.getIV(), Base64.DEFAULT) + "DerivedKey: " +
                Base64.encodeToString(derivedKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, derivedKey, parameterSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

An example of the debug log gives this:

```
2020-07-26 22:40:03.667 9089-9089/com.iso.gallery256 D/decryptByteArray: Size: 45312 IV SPEC: NWZmYmUzZGItZGE4MS00Yw==
    DerivedKey: pa2OYoRLjTphldeSi1L6EQCmlXTzQJLeXgPIuu6kRus=

2020-07-26 22:40:00.184 9089-9089/com.iso.gallery256 D/encryptByteArray: Size: 45307 IV SPEC: NWZmYmUzZGItZGE4MS00Yw==
    DerivedKey: pa2OYoRLjTphldeSi1L6EQCmlXTzQJLeXgPIuu6kRus=
```

I don't think the problem is with how the IV or key are generated, since they come out exactly the same for decryption and encryption, but rather with my cipher options.

Comment: Why you are using  "GCMParameterSpec" instead of "IvParameterSpec" as your algorithm is AES/CBC and not AES/GCM ?

Comment: Wow, that solved the issue. It was a remnant from when I was trying out GCM encryption. I forgot to switch it. Very odd how it works one way but not the other.